# Abstract regular curve over non-algebraically closed field

Tags: extension-field, algebraic-curves, modular-forms

In Hartshorne chapter I.6 is discussed the construction of the abstract nonsingular curve as part of the proof for the well known correspondence between complete regular irreducible algrebaic curves and the function fields in one variable, in the case of algebraically closed ground field.

It seems that Milne (in [his notes on Modular Forms, theorem 2.7, pag. 96](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/MF.pdf)) propose a same construction for the general case (i.e. non algebraically closed ground field), but I couldn't find any reference for the details of this proof in such case. Is there any?

Comment: The construction is essentially the same as in the algebraically closed case.

Comment: I agree that it may be something similar, but I am quite stucked since I cannot define what is a variety over a non algebraically closed field. The whole theory of varieties I have seen depends strongly on Nullstellensatz.

Comment: This certainly works better for schemes. But if you insist in working with classical varieties, you may define a variety over $k \subset \overline{k}$ as something that have equations defined over $k$. The same proof will probably hold. The idea is that by a finite number of removing a rational points you get an affine curve, and then you just pick the fraction field of the affine ring of such a curve. Notice that valuations and prime ideals are the same for Dedekind domains.